# Jquery Tooltip not working on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tooltip

Hey guys I am having problems with my tooltip. Whenever I first load the page I can hover over the image that I have associated with the tooltip. Its the only img in the table mytable so jquery picks it up from that. The problem I am running into is I have a asp.net page that has auto postback, its a form that updates items automatically when you click certain fields. Upon clicking a postback field, I can no longer access the tool-tip. Any idea on what would prevent me from being able to see the tooltip? I am not getting any console errors either.

Comment: What's the markup for the id="mytable" before and after the postback?

Comment: It is still id=mytable, thats what I thought could be the problem at first, but the id remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is the HTML markup for the table with the id "mytable". Seeing an example both before the postback and after is helpful.

Comment: let's see some code!  the html,  the jquery for the tooltip. unless your using live or delegate to set up the tooltip, it makes sense that it isn't there after a re-load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the table in an update panel?  Do you need live/delegate instead of bind?